# Unity3d: CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed

Tags: c#, android, firebase, unity-game-engine, gradle

Project build for Android (Unity3d 2018.3.11f1) worked with previous version of Unity - now i get a error message. Project uses Firebase, complete SDK / NDK / JDK is UpToDate.

Every solution i could find online, but nothing helped.
Configured manuel gradle Template with "multiDexEnabled true" - doesnt help.

// mainTemplate.gradle script:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
**BUILD_SCRIPT_DEPS**}
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
**APPLY_PLUGINS**

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
**DEPS**}

android {
    compileSdkVersion **APIVERSION**
    buildToolsVersion '**BUILDTOOLS**'

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion **MINSDKVERSION**
        targetSdkVersion **TARGETSDKVERSION**
        applicationId '**APPLICATIONID**'
        multiDexEnabled true
        ndk {
            abiFilters **ABIFILTERS**
        }
        versionCode **VERSIONCODE**
        versionName '**VERSIONNAME**'
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    aaptOptions {
        noCompress = ['.unity3d', '.ress', '.resource', '.obb'**STREAMING_ASSETS**]
    }**SIGN**

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled **MINIFY_DEBUG**
            useProguard **PROGUARD_DEBUG**
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'**USER_PROGUARD**
            jniDebuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled **MINIFY_RELEASE**
            useProguard **PROGUARD_RELEASE**
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'**USER_PROGUARD****SIGNCONFIG**
        }
    }**PACKAGING_OPTIONS****SPLITS**
**BUILT_APK_LOCATION**
    bundle {
        language {
            enableSplit = false
        }
        density {
            enableSplit = false
        }
        abi {
            enableSplit = true
        }
    }
}**SPLITS_VERSION_CODE****REPOSITORIES****SOURCE_BUILD_SETUP**


Build should be succeeded, but build fails with: 

Unity3d Console Error Message: 

CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:\Program Files\Unity_2018\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\OpenJDK\Windows\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity_2018\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-4.6.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"

stderr[
D8: Interface `com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient(classpath class)` used as super class of `com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zaag`.
D8: Interface `com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult(classpath class)` used as super class of `com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zacd`.
D8: Type com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzi is referenced as an interface from `com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj`.
D8: Type com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzm is referenced as an interface from `com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzo`.
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process C:\Users\user\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\com.google.android.gms.play-services-basement-16.0.1.aar\f8230c87d6deb512f72f279d7336c818\jars\classes.jar
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:593)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.reportException(ForkJoinTask.java:677)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.join(ForkJoinTask.java:720)
    at com.android.ide.common.internal.WaitableExecutor.waitForTasksWithQuickFail(WaitableExecutor.java:146)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.transform(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:405)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:239)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:235)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:230)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:256)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:249)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:238)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:663)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:597)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process C:\Users\user\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\com.google.android.gms.play-services-basement-16.0.1.aar\f8230c87d6deb512f72f279d7336c818\jars\classes.jar
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.launchProcessing(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:900)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.lambda$convertToDexArchive$6(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:825)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing.
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveBuilder.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveBuilder.java:124)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveBuilder.convert(D8DexArchiveBuilder.java:101)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.launchProcessing(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:895)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:65)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withD8CompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:43)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(D8.java:90)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveBuilder.convert(D8DexArchiveBuilder.java:99)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: Type com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzi is referenced as an interface from `com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj`.
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.failIfPendingErrors(Reporter.java:116)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.fatalError(Reporter.java:74)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:59)
    ... 10 more


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexBuilderForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process C:\Users\user\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\com.google.android.gms.play-services-basement-16.0.1.aar\f8230c87d6deb512f72f279d7336c818\jars\classes.jar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 8s
]
stdout[
:checkReleaseClasspath
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:Firebase:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:Firebase:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:Firebase:checkReleaseManifest
:Firebase:processReleaseManifest
:preReleaseBuild
:Firebase:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
:Firebase:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
:compileReleaseRenderscript
:checkReleaseManifest
:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:prepareLintJar
:mainApkListPersistenceRelease
:generateReleaseResValues
:generateReleaseResources
:Firebase:compileReleaseRenderscript
:Firebase:generateReleaseResValues
:Firebase:generateReleaseResources
:Firebase:packageReleaseResources
:mergeReleaseResources
:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests
:processReleaseManifest
:splitsDiscoveryTaskRelease
:Firebase:generateReleaseRFile
:processReleaseResources
:generateReleaseSources
:Firebase:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:Firebase:prepareLintJar
:Firebase:generateReleaseSources
:Firebase:javaPreCompileRelease
:Firebase:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
:Firebase:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
:Firebase:transformClassesAndResourcesWithPrepareIntermediateJarsForRelease
:javaPreCompileRelease
:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
:compileReleaseNdk NO-SOURCE
:compileReleaseSources
:lintVitalRelease
Calling mockable JAR artifact transform to create file: C:\Users\user\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\android.jar\06bdb78e9df4d37e2a3c0d47f452c0ce\android.jar with input D:\Android\SDK\platforms\android-28\android.jar
:mergeReleaseShaders
:compileReleaseShaders
:generateReleaseAssets
:Firebase:mergeReleaseShaders
:Firebase:compileReleaseShaders
:Firebase:generateReleaseAssets
:Firebase:packageReleaseAssets
:mergeReleaseAssets
:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForRelease
C:\Users\user\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\com.google.android.gms.play-services-measurement-base-16.0.5.aar\39d4c85131c5ce0c1915810729f4b44d\jars\classes.jar: D8: Type `libcore.io.Memory` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `void com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzxj$zzb.zza(long, byte)`
C:\Users\user\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\com.google.android.gms.play-services-measurement-base-16.0.5.aar\39d4c85131c5ce0c1915810729f4b44d\jars\classes.jar: D8: Type `libcore.io.Memory` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `void com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzxj$zza.zza(long, byte)`
:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForRelease FAILED
34 actionable tasks: 34 executed
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1 progress, System.String error)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1 progress)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1 progress)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

When i build the project i get this error message (before console log - maybe this gives some hints i dont see to you)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

Add multidex suppport to your dependencies in mainTemplate.

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])**DEPS**
}
```

Comment: Sadly it didnt worked for me :( - get another gradle fail.

Comment: Can you share your build.gradle file please? I would like to check and eliminate dependencies if any.

Answer (score 0):

This usually means that your build is trying to use multiple versions of same library. Sometimes this does not mean that you specifically have something like this: 
    `'implementation com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0'` 
twice but that an underlying library is pulling same library that either you are pulling. 
For this to make more sense let me give you an example : 
I often use

```
    compile( 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)')
```

Facebook itself needs some libraries to work so it pulls them automatically but you have no control on which version of the library.
So what i often do is the following:

```
    compile( 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)',{

    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'}
```

As I know which support library I require. It is relatively easy to figure out which library pulls what in Android studio however if you are building from Unity perhaps try something like this: 
https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver

I have not tested the above but it might be of help.